# ROS Navigation Stack, Changing Global Planner

Tags: ros, navigation, stack, sbpl, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

How can I change the default Global Planner (Dijkstra) to A* or SBPL.

The tutorial says for example: "The global planner can be used with move_base simply by setting the "base_global_planner" parameter to "SBPLLatticePlanner"".

Where can I set "base_global_planner" parameter?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188257/ros-navigation-stack,-changing-global-planner/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you have mentioned, move_base has a parameter called "base_global_planner" that you can set to whichever planner you want to use. You can do this in the launchfile that launches move_base by adding the following line:

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="your_planner_name"/>
```

The planner has to be of the type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner. You can alternatively supply the parameter from the command line as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools).

---

Originally posted by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) with karma: 1133 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you check this page (http://answers.ros.org/question/171306/how-to-use-global-planner-package-in-hydro-devel-navigation/#172226) ? This article might be useful for you.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1